# Enable MongoDB Secure Replication without breaking replication

Tags: mongodb, replication

When we first set up our multi-region Mongo infrastructure up we didn't add any security and are using unencrypted transport connections for replication over the public internet.  We need to switch to use encrypted connections for the replication, but are worried that switching this will break the current replication.  We have a couple of TB of data and it is very difficult to force a resync if things get out of sync.

What is the recommended process to switch to encrypted transports in this situation?

Thanks in advance,

Ian

Comment: Can you elaborate on the current infrastructure? Is it a replica set with 3 members or more? Is it a sharded cluster? Is the question to enable both authentication and transport encryption?

Comment: It's both.  We have two shards, one in US East, one in US West.  Each region contains a replica set with 3 members.  Does that make sense?  Also should have said this is on Mongo 3.2.18.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabling Secure replication can be done without breaking the apps. If carefully planned, it doesn't require downtime, but restarts. In your case the secondaries of the replica set first followed by the primary. The application would automatically switch over to new primary and it doesn't take long.

Here is the base configuration yaml, that needs to be added. Choose preferSSL option in the config file. With preferSSL as its net.ssl.mode, the node accepts both TLS/SSL and non-TLS/non-SSL incoming connections, and **its connections to other servers use TLS/SSL**.

```
net:
   ssl:
      mode: <disabled|allowSSL|preferSSL|requireSSL>
      PEMKeyFile: <path to TLS/SSL certificate and key PEM file>
      CAFile: <path to root CA PEM file>
```

You can live in this state forever or have application teams switch to use SSL connections. Once everyone is ready to make the switch permanent, use admin command to switch to requireSSL (this will avoid having to restart). Update Mongo config file as well accordingly to use requireSSL (its for future restarts).

Here is the reference documentation on - [enabling Mongo SSL](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/upgrade-cluster-to-ssl/). Since it requires a restart in your case, I would skip directly to step 3 in that doc.